# Uploading files from Firebase Cloud Functions to Cloud Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions) is too complex for me to understand. It shows how to download a file from Cloud Storage to Cloud Functions, manipulate the file, and then upload the new file to Cloud Storage. I just want to see the basic, minimum instructions for uploading a file from Cloud Functions to Cloud Storage. Why doesn't this work:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.storage = functions.firestore.document('Test_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  var metadata = {
    contentType: 'text',
  };

  admin.storage().ref().put( {'test': 'test'}, metadata)
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Document written.");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  })

});
```

The error message is `admin.storage(...).ref is not a function`. I'm guessing that `firebase-admin` includes Firestore but not Storage? Instead of `firebase-admin` should I use `@google-cloud/storage`? Why doesn't this work:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const storage = new Storage();

admin.initializeApp();

exports.storage = functions.firestore.document('Test_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {

  storage.bucket().upload( {'test': 'test'} , {
    metadata: {
      contentType: 'text'
    }
  })

});
```

I can't even deploy this code, the error message is

```
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './clone.js'
```

Apparently a npm module dependency is missing? But the module isn't called `clone.js`? I tried requiring `child-process-promise`, `path`, `os`, and `fs`; none fixed the missing `clone.js` error.

Why does `admin.initializeApp();` lack parameters, when in my `index.html` file I have:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'swordfish',
    authDomain: 'myapp.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: 'myapp',
    storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com"
  });
```

Another issue I'm seeing:

```
npm list -g --depth=0       

/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib
├── child_process@1.0.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY  error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules/firebase-admin/package.json
├── firebase-functions@2.1.0
├── firebase-tools@6.0.1
├── firestore-backup-restore@1.3.1
├── fs@0.0.2
├── npm@6.4.1
├── npm-check@5.9.0
├── protractor@5.4.1
├── request@2.88.0
└── watson-developer-cloud@3.13.0
```

In other words, there's something wrong with `firebase-admin`, or with `Node 6.11.2`. Should I use a Node Version Manager to revert to an older version of Node?

Comment: Same pain here, I'm guessing we should use this API reference.. https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I uploaded a file from my hard drive to Firebase Cloud Storage via Google Cloud Functions. First, I found the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/) for Google Cloud Functions [bucket.upload](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/2.0.x/Bucket#upload).

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
    
    exports.Storage = functions.firestore.document('Storage_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    
      const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
      const storage = new Storage();
      const bucket = storage.bucket('myapp.appspot.com');
    
      const options = {
        destination: 'Test_Folder/hello_world.dog'
      };
    
      bucket.upload('hello_world.ogg', options).then(function(data) {
        const file = data[0];
      });
    
      return 0;
    });
```

The first three lines are Cloud Functions boilerplate. The next line

```js
    exports.Storage = functions.firestore.document('Storage_Value').onUpdate((change, context) => {
```

creates the Cloud Function and sets the trigger. The next three lines are more Google Cloud boilerplate.

The rest of the code locates the file `hello_world.ogg` on my computer's hard drive in the `functions` folder of my project directory and uploads it to the directory `Test_Folder` and changes the name of the file to `hello_world.dog` in my Firebase Cloud Storage. This returns a promise, and the next line `const file = data[0];` is unnecessary unless you want to do something else with the file.

Lastly we `return 0;`. This line does nothing except prevent the error message

```
Function returned undefined, expected Promise or Value
```

Answer (score 13):

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam
2. Click the pencil icon next to your `App Engine default service account`
3. `+ ADD ANOTHER ROLE`
4. Add `Cloud Functions Service Agent`

In my specific use case, I needed to decode a base64 string into a byte array and then use that to save the image.

```
    var serviceAccount = require("./../serviceAccountKey.json");

    import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
    import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';    

    admin.initializeApp({
        projectId: serviceAccount.project_id, 
        credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
        databaseURL: "https://your_project_id_here.firebaseio.com", //update this
        storageBucket: "your_bucket_name_here.appspot.com" //update this
      });

    function uploadProfileImage(imageBytes64Str: string): Promise<any> {

        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
        const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(imageBytes64Str, 'base64')
        const imageByteArray = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer);
        const file = bucket.file(`images/profile_photo.png`);
        const options = { resumable: false, metadata: { contentType: "image/jpg" } }

        //options may not be necessary
        return file.save(imageByteArray, options)
        .then(stuff => {
            return file.getSignedUrl({
                action: 'read',
                expires: '03-09-2500'
              })
        })
        .then(urls => {
            const url = urls[0];
            console.log(`Image url = ${url}`)
            return url
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(`Unable to upload image ${err}`)
        })
    }
```

---

Then you can call the method like this and chain the calls.

```
    uploadProfileImage(image_bytes_here)
    .then(url => {
        //Do stuff with the url here        
    })
```

---

Note: You must initialize admin with a service account and specify the default bucket. **If you simply do `admin.initializeApp()` then your image urls will expire in 10 days.**

Steps to properly use a service account.

1. Go to [Service Accounts](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts) and generate a private key
2. Put the JSON file in your functions folder (next to src and node_modules)
3. Go to [Storage](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/storage) and copy the URL not including the "gs://" in the front. Use this for the storage bucket url when initializing admin.
4. Use your project ID above for the database URL.

Comment: thanks. I'm a little bit surprised all of this is needed. Firestore (database) works out of the box?

Answer (score 6):

> See [Introduction to the Admin Cloud Storage
>   API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) for further
>   details on how to use the Cloud Storage service in Firebase Admin SDK.
>
> ```
> var admin = require("firebase-admin");
>
> var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");
>
> admin.initializeApp({
>     credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
>     storageBucket: "<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com"
> });
>
> var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
>
> // 'bucket' is an object defined in the @google-cloud/storage library.
> // See https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/latest/storage/bucket
> // for more details.
> ```

Regarding uploading objects, see [Cloud Storage Documentation Uploading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code_sample) sample code:

> ```
> // Imports the Google Cloud client library
> const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
>
> // Creates a client
> const storage = new Storage();
>
> /**
>  * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
>  */
> // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';
> // const filename = 'Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt';
>
> // Uploads a local file to the bucket
> await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
>   // Support for HTTP requests made with `Accept-Encoding: gzip`
>   gzip: true,
>   metadata: {
>     // Enable long-lived HTTP caching headers
>     // Use only if the contents of the file will never change
>     // (If the contents will change, use cacheControl: 'no-cache')
>     cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000',
>   },
> });
>
> console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
> ```

Comment: That code creates a bucket but doesn't upload a file to Storage.

Comment: For 2nd code block, adding field/value `destination : 'test/coffeeLogo.png'` to the **.upload()** options JSON completes the file upload - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54227249, and in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181557

Answer (score 0):

For people coming here, wondering why they don't get an error but files do not appear in the Online console while debugging locally.

Solution: Don't start the storage emulator locally.

I.e., when you just want to debug functions: `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions --only functions`

Answer (score -1):

```
if (req.rawBody) {
    busboy.end(req.rawBody);
}
else {
    req.pipe(busboy);
}
```

As described in this issue: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/issues/161#issuecomment-376563784