# Firebase onFinalize doesn't trigger for functions emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, emulation, firebase-tools

I'm setting up the env for local development and just testing to see if the emulators are working but my simple test is failing without any errors.

```
// functions/index.js
exports.pdftoimg = functions.storage.object().onFinalize(async (object) => {
  console.log({ object });
});
```

Emulators start without issues:

```
firebase emulators:start
i  emulators: Starting emulators: auth, functions, firestore, hosting, pubsub, storage
✔  functions: Using node@16 from host.
i  hosting: Serving hosting files from: dist
✔  hosting: Local server: http://localhost:5002
i  functions: Watching "/Users/xxx/Code/myApp/functions" for Cloud Functions...
✔  functions[us-central1-pdftoimg]: storage function initialized.

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! It is now safe to connect your app. │
│ i  View Emulator UI at http://localhost:4000                │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

But when I upload a test pdf file to storage emulator using the UI (http://localhost:4000/storage/default-bucket) nothing is displayed in the logs.

I tested the cloud triggers for Firestore Db but that seems to work though.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: If the emulator is just not working the way you expect, you should file a bug with repro instructions and logs on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are [Triggering a Cloud Function on Cloud Storage Changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/extend-with-functions#trigger-function-on-storage-changes) that returns the uploaded [object metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage.objectmetadata).

However, this function does not upload the file:

> `onFinalize` Sent when a new object (or a new generation of an existing object) is successfully created in the bucket. This includes copying or rewriting an existing object. A failed upload does not trigger this event.

In that case please follow the documentation provided to [Upload Files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files).
Finally, adding [Error Handling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/handle-errors) to your code will help you the next time as in this case you have no logs or anything to debug the error.

**Update:**

This issue [onFinalize trigger not working in emulator](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4014), that uses the same Cloud Functions with the same results. We have to wait for support on that.

After some research a colleague found this github issue that uses the same documentation and the same methods you are using.
The first one describes how [‘onFinalize’ is triggered even on failed upload](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3772): and also redirects to the documentation that was mentioned above. In this case the function is triggered when it’s not supposed to, you can try executing it like this.

Comment: Are you saying that uploading programatically instead of uploading via Web UI would trigger `onFinalize`? Sure, I can try that to confirm but if thats the case then its indeed a bug. It shouldn't matter *how* the object was created in the bucket.

Comment: No, sorry. I meant that you might not be receiving the data correctly, and/or you are not using the correct upload method in case of any. I was not able to find any example on how to treat this data, but I linked the documentation of the object metadata, you might want to try to get only certain properties and see if it works, E.g.: `object.name`, `object.metadata`. I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53181557/16938011) that might help.

Comment: @eozzy just wondering if you have already read the update in my answer and hoping you could provide some feedback.

Comment: this solved the issue for me: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/4014#issuecomment-1021609657

Comment: Great, if that link mentioned in my answer was useful, could you please consider upvoting my answer, as it could help future users that see this discussion?